# Nessus IO Powershell API HTML/PDF report

Tags: powershell, rest, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, nessus

When exporting PDF & HTML format reports the reports are empty, best I can tell there needs to be a report attribute but after 5 hours of running through the API and searching every which way I can think of I am not finding anything referencing that.

For those interested, this is the starting script before I started optimizing it.

https://github.com/Pwd9000-ML/NessusV7-Report-Export-PowerShell/blob/master/NessusPro_v7_Report_Exporter_Tool.ps1

```
add-type @" 
    using System.Net; 
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; 
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy { 
        public bool CheckValidationResult( 
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate, 
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) { 
                return true; 
                } 
    } 
"@ 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$GNR = @{
    OutputDir = "$Env:SystemDrive\Nessus\$(([DateTime]::Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))"
    StatusUri = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
}

#------------------Input Variables----------------------------------------------------------------- 
$Baseurl = "https://$($env:COMPUTERNAME):8834"
$Username = <Removed>
$Password = <Removed>
$ContentType = "application/json"
$POSTMethod = 'POST' 
$GETMethod = 'GET'

#------------------Stage props to obtain session token (Parameters)-------------------------------- 
$session = @{ 
    Uri         = $Baseurl + "/session" 
    ContentType = $ContentType 
    Method      = $POSTMethod 
    Body        = convertto-json (New-Object PSObject -Property @{username = $Username; password = $Password})
} 

#------------------Commit session props for token header X-cookie---------------------------------- 
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @session
if ($TokenResponse) { 
    $Header = @{"X-Cookie" = "token=" + $TokenResponse.token} 
} else {
    Write-nLog -Message "Error occured obtaining session token. Script Terminating... Please ensure Username and Password Correct." -Type Error -TerminatingError
} 

IF (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($GNR.OutputDir)) {
    New-Item -Path $GNR.OutputDir  -ItemType directory -Force |Out-Null
}

#------------------Output completed scans---------------------------------------------------------- 
$Scans = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$baseurl/scans" -Headers $Header -Method $GETMethod -ContentType "application/json").scans

ForEach ($Format in @("nessus","pdf")) {
    $StatusURI = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    $StatusArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    ForEach ($Scan in $Scans) {
        Add-Content -Path "$($GNR.OutputDir)\ScanReport.txt" -Value "$($Scan.Name) ($($Scan.status))"
        IF ($Scan.status -eq "Completed") {
            $File = (Invoke-RestMethod -URI "$baseurl/scans/$($Scan.ID)/export" -ContentType $ContentType -Headers $Header -Method $POSTMethod -Body $(convertto-json (New-Object PSObject -Property @{format = "$Format"}))).file
            [Void]$StatusArray.Add(
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    ScanName    = $scan.name
                    StatusUri   = $baseurl + "/scans" + "/" + $Scan.id + "/export/" + "$file" + "/status"
                    DownloadUri = $baseurl + "/scans" + "/" + $Scan.id + "/export/" + "$file" + "/download"
                }
            )
        }
    }
    #------------------Check Status of Export requests------------------------------------------------- 
    While ($StatusArray.StatusUri.count -GT $StatusURI.Count) {
        ForEach ($ScanStatus in $StatusArray.StatusURI) {
            IF ((Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ScanStatus -ContentType $ContentType -Headers $Header -Method $GETMethod).status -EQ "Ready") {
                if ($StatusURI -notcontains $ScanStatus) {
                    Write-Host "Adding $ScanStatus"
                    [void]$StatusURI.Add($ScanStatus)
                }
            } Else {
                Write-nLog -Type "Info" -Message "Not all scans complete. ($($GNR.StatusURI.Count)/$($StatusArray.StatusUri.count)"
                Start-Sleep -s 5
            }
        }
    }

    #------------------Download the Reports------------------------------------------------------------ 
    $ExportUri = $StatusArray.DownloadUri
    $outputs = $StatusArray.ScanName

    foreach ($i in 0..($ExportUri.Count - 1)) {
        Write-nLog -Type Info -Message "Exporting Report: $($outputs[$i])"
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ExportUri[$i] -ContentType $ContentType -Headers $Header -Method $GETMethod -OutFile "$($GNR.OutputDir)\$($outputs[$i]).$Format"                  
    }
}
#------------------Script END----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several additional parameters you can set on the `POST /scans/{id}/export` endpoint. The important one missed here is `chapters` which accepts a semi-colon delimted list of the desired content sections. This must be set for exports of `pdf` or `html` types, otherwise you get an empty result.

For example, to get the executive summary, in addition to `format` of `html`/`pdf`/`csv` etc, set `chapters` to `vuln_hosts_summary`. The other available options are:

- `vuln_by_host`
- `compliance_exec`
- `remediations`
- `vuln_by_plugin`
- `compliance`

Hopefully this helps the next person trying to debug empty Nessus API exports too!

For full API docs for your version check out `https://{YOUR_NESSUS_INSTALL}/api`